# What is the name/notation for the unary operator on a sequence variable for expressing the number of elements in said sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, terminology

Given a sequence $x$, what is the name/notation for the unary operator that operates on $x$ to express the number of elements in $x$?

- e.g. If $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$, then the unary operator operating on $x$ would yield $3$.
- e.g. If $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, ... \infty)$, then the unary operator operating on $x$ would yield $\infty$.

**What I am not asking:**

- the length of a vector $||v||$
- the dimension of a vector space $V$

**Analogy for what I am asking:**

The unary operator in question operates similar to how the cardinality operator operates on a set variable (e.g. if $\ X = \{4, 9, 3\}$, then $(|X| = 3)\equiv true$.)

**Edit: 08 July 2023**

Updated the title and body of this question to request the notation/name of the operator.

Comment: Why not just call it the "length" of the sequence? Everyone will understand what it does, especially with accompanying examples.

Comment: Something like $length(x)$? Sounds good in terms of a function. However, I'm looking more for a single-character operator, or at least something a little more terse. Does any such operator exist?

Comment: I think you're asking about the name/notation for this operator (the operator as a mathematical object definitely exists). Like any function, you can give it a name ("$L$"?) and use that name thereafter.

Comment: Ah, yep. I am asking about notation. I will edit the question. Thanks Greg.

Comment: "length", which is tantamount to "dimension" (of the sequence)

Comment: You *can* write $f(S,i) = \delta_{i,\operatorname{dim}(S)}$ where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta, and $S$ the sequence.